Install OpenSSL library for CMake project
I've downloaded a stable release of OpenSSL library, and I am surprised that the oldest package don't have a CMakeList.txt for add_subdirectory(vendor/openssl).
So far, OpenSSL is built under Linux, but I want to build it under Android and Windows too.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0076 NEW)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0091 NEW)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0071 NEW)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(PROJECT_NAME Control)
set(APP_VERSION 0.1.0)

project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION ${APP_VERSION} LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(vendor/libzip)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    Core
    Gui
    Quick
    Network
    NetworkAuth
    Sql
    Positioning
    Widgets
    QuickWidgets
    UiTools
    Xml
    QUIET
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")

qt_policy(SET QTP0001 NEW)

qt_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    MANUAL_FINALIZATION
    resources.qrc
    ${HEADERS}
    ${SOURCES}
)

qt_add_qml_module(${PROJECT_NAME}
    URI control
    VERSION ${APP_VERSION}
    RESOURCES
    android/AndroidManifest.xml
    android/src/org/control/AndroidAPI.java
    SOURCES
    ${HEADERS}
    ${SOURCES}
)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(ExternalProject)

set(ANDROID_NDK_ROOT "~/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393")

set(ANDROID_ABI "arm64-v8a")
set(ANDROID_PLATFORM "android-29")

ExternalProject_Add(
    openssl
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/vendor/openssl
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
    GIT_TAG OpenSSL_3_0_0
    CMAKE_ARGS
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR>
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
        -DOPENSSL_NO_SHARED=ON
        -DANDROID_ABI=${ANDROID_ABI}
        -DANDROID_PLATFORM=${ANDROID_PLATFORM}
        -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
        -DANDROID_NDK=${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(openssl install_dir)
set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR ${install_dir}/include)
set(OPENSSL_LIBRARIES ${install_dir}/lib/libssl.a ${install_dir}/lib/libcrypto.a)

include_directories(${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    Qt6::Core
    Qt6::Gui
    Qt6::Quick
    Qt6::Network
    Qt6::NetworkAuth
    Qt6::Sql
    Qt6::Positioning
    Qt6::Widgets
    Qt6::Xml
    Qt6::QuickWidgets
    Qt6::UiTools
    libzip::zip
    ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}
)

# Ensure the project depends on OpenSSL
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} openssl)

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} APPEND PROPERTY
    QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android
)

qt_finalize_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION .
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
)


I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to build openssl a component of your existing project?

Yes. OpenSSL built under Linux. But my project is cross-platform. And of course I can't to install lib openssl-dev under android.

You're probably way better off just building openssl on its own, then pointing your cmake at the pre-built binaries.  A quick glance a the project documentaiton shows quite a few platform-specific notes.

You have to use execute_process of CMake to call Configure tool that comes with OpenSSL.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0076 NEW)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0091 NEW)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0071 NEW)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(APP_ID Control)
set(APP_VERSION 0.1.0)

project(${APP_ID} VERSION ${APP_VERSION} LANGUAGES CXX)

set(OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/vendor/openssl")  # Путь к подмодулю
set(OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/vendor/openssl/install")    # Директория установки

# Устанавливаем уровень параллельной сборки
set(CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL 8)

# Проверка на существование симлинка
if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/openssl_src")
    execute_process(
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink ${OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/openssl_src
    )
else()
    message(STATUS "Symlink already exists: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/openssl_src")
endif()


# Определяем, на какой платформе происходит сборка
if(ANDROID)

    # Параметры для сборки под Android
    set(ANDROID_NDK_ROOT "~/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393")
    set(ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN "${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64")
    set(ANDROID_SYSROOT "${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN}/sysroot")

    set(PATH "${ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN}/bin:${ANDROID_SYSROOT}/usr/bin:${PATH}")
    set(OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_TARGET "android-x86_64")
    set(OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_FLAGS "-D__ANDROID_API__=33")

    # Проверка на существование библиотеки
    if(NOT EXISTS "${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libssl.a" OR NOT EXISTS "${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.a")
        message(STATUS "Building OpenSSL...")
        execute_process(
            COMMAND ./Configure ${OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_TARGET} --prefix=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR} ${OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_FLAGS}
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/openssl_src
        )
        execute_process(
            COMMAND make -j ${CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL}
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/openssl_src
        )
        execute_process(
            COMMAND make install
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/openssl_src
        )
    else()
        message(STATUS "OpenSSL libraries already exist.")
    endif()

else()
    # Параметры для сборки под стандартные системы (Linux, Windows)
    if(WIN32)
        set(OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_TARGET "VC-WIN64A")
    elseif(UNIX AND NOT ANDROID)
        set(OPENSSL_CONFIGURE_TARGET "linux-x86_64")
    endif()

    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libssl.a ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.a
        COMMAND ./config --prefix=${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}
        COMMAND make -j ${CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL}
        COMMAND make install
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR}
        DEPENDS ${OPENSSL_SOURCE_DIR}/Configure
    )
endif()

# Добавление целей для сборки OpenSSL
add_custom_target(openssl ALL DEPENDS ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libssl.a ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.a)

# Интеграция с основным проектом
include_directories(${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/include)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    Core
    Gui
    Quick
    Network
    NetworkAuth
    Sql
    Positioning
    Widgets
    QuickWidgets
    UiTools
    Xml
    QUIET)

# Поиск всех исходных и заголовочных файлов в директории `src`
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h")
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")

qt_policy(SET QTP0001 NEW)

qt_add_executable(${APP_ID}
    MANUAL_FINALIZATION
    resources.qrc
    ${HEADERS}
    ${SOURCES}
)

qt_add_qml_module(${APP_ID}
    URI control
    VERSION ${APP_VERSION}

    RESOURCES
    android/AndroidManifest.xml
    android/src/org/control/AndroidAPI.java

    SOURCES
    ${HEADERS}
    ${SOURCES}
)

set_target_properties(${APP_ID} PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

add_subdirectory(vendor/libzip)

# Установите свойства для целевого приложения
set_target_properties(${APP_ID} PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(${APP_ID}
    PRIVATE
    Qt6::Core
    Qt6::Gui
    Qt6::Quick
    Qt6::Network
    Qt6::NetworkAuth
    Qt6::Sql
    Qt6::Positioning
    Qt6::Widgets
    Qt6::Xml
    Qt6::QuickWidgets
    Qt6::UiTools
    libzip::zip
    ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libssl.a
    ${OPENSSL_INSTALL_DIR}/lib/libcrypto.a
)

add_dependencies(${APP_ID} openssl)

set_property(TARGET ${APP_ID} APPEND PROPERTY
    QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android
)

qt_finalize_executable(${APP_ID})

install(TARGETS ${APP_ID}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION .
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
)


Could you please add an explanation to this solution? The comments are not in English. Read [answer] to better understand how to contribute answers on Stack Overflow and benefit future readers.
